# 100 animated pics on an Android screen

Tags: android, graphics, interpolation, game-physics, physics-engine

Imagine emptying a pouch having 100 stamps on a small area. That would be the starting point for my screen. I should be able to scale individual stamps in and out, animate them on a swiping gesture, overlay them and animate them so they all come towards the place of a former stamp that just got swiped out of screen, filling that space in. Plus zooming and panning over the entire screen. 
I have made canvas level zooming, panning, and drawing by hand, but I feel this is going to benefit a lot from some kind of library. What should I be looking for ? Math libraries, physics, game engines ?
I don't suppose making these into `ImageView`s and all together into a `ViewGroup` and trying to make it work from there would be a good idea.

Thanks

Comment: you can probably draw them all on a single bitmap, attach a gesture detector and redraw them based on gesture

Comment: @Sourabh on a single canvas you mean ? Sure I could. But I foresee some maths having to get rolled over in my code.